# Как создать переменную командой в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в Python создать переменную командой. Допустим, будет так:

```
name = input("Введите имя переменной: ")
value = input("Введите значение переменной: ")
```

Можно ли благодаря этим данным создать переменную?

Comment: один вопрос - зачем?

Comment: Можно, но лучше так никогда не делать. Почти всегда, когда возникает такая идея, гораздо лучшим решением будет просто использовать словарь.